# NotFoundHttpException in laravel Auth login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

i can't login with `Auth` in `laravel` i got an error `NotFoundHttpException`
my form for login

```
<form id="login-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
```

My file Router.php

```
public function auth(){
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
}
```

My route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
 Route::get('home', 'NavmenuController@menuright')->name('home');
}
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('auth.login');
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: `action="{{ route('login') }}"` sends your form to a page which expects `get` request whereas your form sends `post` request

Comment: yes i see. But i can't login

Comment: In your console try `route:list` and see what is the name of the url you should use

Comment: or use `url('/login')` instead of `route('login')`

Comment: @TheRock : Also try with `action="/login"` first to check it exist or not

Comment: @TheRock : Not working means what error you are getting ?

Comment: @programmingArrow that's not working

Comment: @user2486 i got an error NotFoundHttpException

Comment: if you have route `$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');` and try like `action="/login"` then it should work. Also share what you get in `route:list` . update in your question ?

Comment: Try clearing the route cache `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @user2486 when i put action="/login" it will clear my url to my domain and login like this http://172.167.11.101/login

Comment: @TheRock : and what is your expected ?

Comment: @user2486 i want to verify with auth login and then go to my dashboard by route home in my question

Comment: @linktoahref not working

Comment: Are you going to `login` function `LoginController` ?

Comment: @user2486 yes loginController in Auth Laravel

Comment: Remove middleware from routes and then try

Comment: @programmingArrow still can't login :(

Comment: you removed middleware from both urls?

Comment: @programmingArrow yes i already remove middleware from my route but it's still not working

Comment: please provide NavmenuController code and also what is router.php doing?

Comment: @programmingArrow i think because of laravel version

Comment: i use laravel 5.4.38

Answer (score 0):

Make `login` for post to named route. Change from

```
 $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

to

```
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
```

Comment: @TheRock , Try by adding `/` as `$this->post('/login'` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

where is the named route assign?? change to this.

```
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('post_login');
and in your form add this

<form id="login-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('post_login') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the native Auth of laravel then just add this line in routes.php it will handle all routes of authentications

> Auth::routes();

Comment: put it on the top of all routes